# error: use of overloaded operator '*' is ambiguous

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, reference

When I try to compile this source in c++:

```
void ParticleSystem::setState(std::vector<Vec2f>& statesVector)
{
    std::vector<Vec2f> pState(2);
    for (int i = 0; i < 2*np; i += 2) {
        pState[0] = *statesVector[i];
        pState[1] = *(statesVector[i+1]);
        (*particles[i/2]).setState(pState);
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
ParticleSystem.cpp:110:15: error: use of overloaded operator '*' is ambiguous (operand type
  'value_type' (aka 'gfx::TVec2<float>'))
            pState[0] = *statesVector[i];
                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
ParticleSystem.cpp:110:15: note: built-in candidate operator*(float *)
ParticleSystem.cpp:110:15: note: built-in candidate operator*(const float *)
ParticleSystem.cpp:111:15: error: use of overloaded operator '*' is ambiguous (operand type
  'value_type' (aka 'gfx::TVec2<float>'))
            pState[1] = *(statesVector[i+1]);
```

I have look for the error already in the forums and followed some steps but i never get to make it work. Moreover, I've also tried to understand the explanation in the notes of the error, but I cannot.
I really hope someone can help me.

Finally, if someone rates this question negatively, at least explain why, please.

Comment: Is `Vec2f` a function pointer?

Comment: `statesVector[i]` evaluates to `Vec2f&`. There is no unary operator `*` defined for a `Vec2f`. It's not clear what you intend to do in the line.

Comment: And fyi, `operator []` has [higher precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) than `operator *` regardless. You should probably distinguish what you're *really* trying to do in the first place. And please indicate *in your question* what a `Vec2f` actually *is*. There are numerous toolkits that declare types by that name, and you've given no concrete indication which you're using. An *real* [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would help *immensely*.

Comment: you don't need the `*` if you just want to affect the value of your `statesVector`. References don't need the `*` operator to get the value.

Comment: @meneldal , that was the answer. Thank you all!

Comment: I just posted an answer so you can accept it and remove the question from the unanswered list (or you could delete the question all together if you want)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you didn't understand the syntax that comes with references. While you do declare a reference with `&`, you use it as you would use the actual variable and not like a pointer, which means you can't use the operator `*` on it (unless it's a reference on a pointer type). Using the `*` operator produces the same effects as if you were to use it on a regular variable.

You can fix your problem by removing the `*` in your code like this:

```
    pState[0] = statesVector[i];
    pState[1] = statesVector[i+1];
    particles[i/2].setState(pState);
```

Your code could compile as is if you defined `operator*` in the `Vec2f` class and made it return a `Vec2f`. However, this make little sense in a semantics point of view (a dereferenced value should not give something of the same type) so this is not the way to fix your problem.